# Actions on Google- Personality quiz- Database update failed error

Tags: actions-on-google, google-developers-console

Why am I getting this error when I upload my Google sheet in Actions on Google Personality Quiz- 'It looks like something went wrong in the upload process. We weren't able to determine the format of your Google Sheet.'

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you add your quiz data to the default sheet provided by the Actions Console wizard. Also, don't edit any of the blue rows near the top of each sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in google sheet down left corner u have  "configuration "part just change "Title of quiz same as your quiz name".I hope it will help